# Autodesk Viewer problem and missing elements from translation to SVF

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk, revit, autodesk-model-derivative

I've been trying to encourage some of our less Revit-savvy building services engineers to utilise the Autodesk Viewer product. Unfortunately though, I have encountered a couple of problems, one of which I think I have solved and one which I am guessing is more to do with the Autodesk Viewer Applications programmed interaction with the model derivative API.

Initially I uploaded our services model with supporting architectural and structural models but the phase the solitary 3D view created in the viewer was "Existing" with a filter of "Show All". I managed to get around this by creating a 3D view in each model just called "3D" and setting the phase and filter as I like. Happy days.

- Could this also have been better solved by setting generateMasterViews to true during the POST job on a custom Forge viewer app?

However, I am only getting some elements from the services model come through into the Autodesk Viewer application. Most notably it's missing ducts, sanitary pipework, cable trays, radiators. In the "3D" 3D view I have created everything is phased correctly, no issues from worksets, visibility graphics, view discipline is coordination (doesnt work to change to mechanical) and everything looks hunky dory in Revit. In the viewer though it's a different story. Even if I upload the services model on it's own. Strangely, in the 2d sheet views all the equipment and infrastructure is there fine, just in 3D it is now.

So my knowledge of Javascript and the Forge API is quite rudimental but I'm guessing the problem is with Autodesk Viewer's implementation of the model derivative API for when the model is translated to svf.

- Does this sound correct?
- Could it a bug within Autodesk's viewer app? I'm not too sure what the best Autodesk forum to post in would be.
- Could it be a bug within the model derivative API? Or is it a setting that is beyond my knowledge?

I guessing I'm at a place where what I'm really after is a custom Forge viewer application to design in the functionality I am after, in this case control of phasing in the .svf file output and ensuring everything is coming through in the view.

Not the most interesting post by any stretch and if you're still reading now, thanks. But I'm sure I can't be the only one experiencing this problem. While I'd love to share a model to demonstrate whats happening, it's commercially sensitive unfortunately.

If anyone can shed a more technical light on

Cheers,Pete

Answer (score 0):

Hi please make sure those elements are visible in 3D views and those 3D views are chosen in the publish settings of the Revit UI. Otherwise, the Model Derivative API will translate the default 3D view called {3D} only that might not contents proper element visibility configurations.

If this issue still persists after setting this up, please consider providing a none confidential model to forge[DOT]help[AT]autodesk[DOT]com for investigations. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your response Eason, I will try your recommendations and see if I have any success. Cheers, Pete

Comment: Hi Eason, problem solved by creating a publish set with what I need. 

What I failed to understand was that modification was required to the publish settings in order to send to the viewer the views and sheets required and to stop it from automatically publishing a default 3D view and all sheets. 

Thanks again for your response. 

Cheers, Pete

Comment: You're welcome! It's great to hear that it works on your side. Most of Forge starters on Revit area might encounter this issue when they use Forge for the first time as I know, I will discuss with our team if there is somewhere we can put a guide for troubleshooting such issue. Cheers! :)